# How to change version without updating entity data in optimistic_force_increment hibernate jpa?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, locking

I am new to Hibernate JPA.
As I understand the optimistic_force_increment in hibernate jpa: if the entity is updated anywhere in a transaction when updated entity commits, it updates the version field column in database.

Now my question is, is there any way to update the @version field without updating any data inside the entity?

Highly appreciate a code snippet or example to do the same.

Comment: What would be the reason doing that? Testing? Do you want to update the version field in entity itself or only in db?

Comment: Basically there are some external entities which are not foreign keys of current entities but use the data from current entity. and in concurrency context, I want to lock the entity without changing its data.

Comment: I haven't fully understand why you should do this but it sounds like a workaround in a problem you have. Why don't you analyze the problem further instead of implementing in anti-pattern way. If I have understood correctly you might need a dto (data transfer object).

Comment: Not understanding it does not make it an anti-pattern ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is workaround: you could evict and add entity to session, look at this snippet:

```
    public void forceUpdate(Object aEntity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInHibernate(Session aSession) throws HibernateException {
                if (aSession.contains(aEntity)) {
                    aSession.evict(aEntity);
                }
                aSession.update(aEntity);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article:
https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-increase-version-parent-entity-updating-child-entity/

For increasing the version without updating it, the author proposes the following:

```
TypedQuery q = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.id = 1", Book.class);
q.setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
Book b = q.getSingleResult();
```

Additionally look at this article, that also deals with this question and proposes how this can be automatically done via event listeners:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/